# Properly setting up LuaBinaries files on Windows?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to setup the files from LuaBinaries (specifically Lua 5.2.4 64-bit), and there are a few things I'm confused about.

There are two zip files provided, the binaries: `lua-*_Win*_bin.zip` and the libraries: `lua-*_Win*_*_lib.zip`

So, these are my questions:

1. For the libraries, two versions are provided, static and dynamic. What's the difference?
2. The zip file for the dynamic libraries contains a `lua*.dll`, but a file with the same name is provided in the zip file for the binaries. Which one should I use?
3. Some of the library zip files (the older ones?) contains a `liblua*.a` file, is this supposed to be a misnamed `lua*.lib` file?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. For the libraries, two versions are provided, static and dynamic. What's the difference?

The static library can be *embedded into* your own program. While the dynamic library is *linked to* your program, so the system will search for it when running your program. If the search for the dynamic library failed, the system won't be able to run your program correctly.

> 2. The zip file for the dynamic libraries contains a lua*.dll, but a file with the same name is provided in the zip file for the binaries. Which one should I use?

The lua*.dll under `lua-*_Win*_bin.zip` is the *d*ynamic *l*ink *l*ibrary(.dll) used by lua.exe and luac.exe. An error will be thrown by Windows if you run lua.exe after deleting it.

Which one should you use? It depends on your purpose. **Usually you want to use the static library in you project.**

- Running different versions of Lua bytecode (e.g., runs the bytecode created by luac v5.1.4 with lua v5.2.4) is forbidden (by checking the header of bytecode files).
- Lua sometimes brings breaking changes upon upgrading, and some public APIs vary between different versions. If you build and install Lua from source code, only the binaries and the static library are produced.
- Lua is a very tiny language (the static library under Linux is about 356K(v5.1.4) or 440K(v5.3.3), measured by `du -sh liblua.a`), so embedding the static library with your program is fine for many high-end devices.

If you feel familiar with `make` command, you can build Lua from source code and load it into your project. Or, **just use the static library in your project.** (I don't think most Windows users have a lua*.dll in their enviroment.)

> 3. Some of the library zip files (the older ones?) contains a liblua*.a file, is this supposed to be a misnamed lua*.lib file?

No, the libxxx.a and libxxx.so is the static and dynamic library naming conventions under *nix systems, like Linux and FreeBSD.